# Firebase promise not fulfilling - MERN app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am using code almost exactly as per the Firebase docs, but for whatever reason my async function is not able to fulfil the promise and the .then() block is never triggered.

The code:

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      // console.log("REGISTER STATE =======>", registerState);
      await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registerState.email, registerState.password)
        .then((user) => {
          console.log("REGISTER", user);
          history.push("/");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //console.log(err);
          toast.dark(err.message, {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: 5000,
            hideProgressBar: false,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            });
          setLoading(false);
        });
    };
```

I've also tried this since maybe I shouldn't be using .then with a promise:

```
    const onSubmit = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log("REGISTER STATE =======> ", registerState.email);
      try {
        console.log("starting the try catch")
        const user = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registerState.email, registerState.password)
            console.log("REGISTER USER =======> ", user);
            history.push("/login");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("REGISTER REQUEST ERROR =======> ", err);
        toast.dark(err.message, {
          position: "top-center",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          });
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
```

In the first case the await is triggered as I see the user created in Firebase, but the .then() doesn't trigger as the user is never logged to the console.

In the second case the user is only created in firebase when the form is submitted twice (weird), and still no user object from firebase is returned (i.e. nothing is logged to the console).

In both cases there is no error shown in the console, the terminal or the .catch (which works - for example if I try a 3 character password I get the error response that passwords need to be >= 6 characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was including a preventDefault clause, if anyone stumbles upon the same problem in the future!